# Strange error of compilation with beamer, extract and \hyperref package

Tags: beamer, errors, extract

I noticed a strange error of compilation.

After multiple tests, I noticed url and `\href{}{}` from `hyperref` package systematically generated the following error

```
 main.tex, line 31
Runaway argument?

{https://www.geogebra.org/m/ydz69yUz}{\beamerbutton {Méthode de 
Newt\ETC.
! Paragraph ended before \next was complete.
<to be read again> 
                \par 
l.31 \end{frame}
```

I am not as expert as most of you. But I lost my French on this question.

Here is MWE

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[active,generate=file.tex]{extract}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
{Geogebra}

\begin{extract}
\href{https://www.geogebra.org/m/ydz69yUz}{Description}
\url{https://www.geogebra.org/m/ntbtfxGJ}
\url{https://www.geogebra.org/m/Ehnz3hGb}
\end{extract}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if combining the `extract` package with beamer is a good idea -- depending on what you like to accomplish, there might be better ways.

Anyway, you can make your document compile by using a `fragile` frame. Note that the resulting `file.tex` is not really usable, it should wrap the contents in a frame environment.

Also note that you don't need to load `hyperref` with beamer.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[active,generate=file.tex]{extract}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
\frametitle{Geogebra}

\begin{extract}
\href{https://www.geogebra.org/m/ydz69yUz}{Description}
\url{https://www.geogebra.org/m/ntbtfxGJ}
\url{https://www.geogebra.org/m/Ehnz3hGb}
\end{extract}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

---

Another solution is to use the `extract` environment outside of a frame:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[active,generate=file.tex]{extract}

\begin{document}

\begin{extract}
\href{https://www.geogebra.org/m/ydz69yUz}{Description}
\url{https://www.geogebra.org/m/ntbtfxGJ}
\url{https://www.geogebra.org/m/Ehnz3hGb}
\end{extract}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Geogebra}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you @samcarter ! I basically tried to extract all the urls to send them to my students. I don't like sending the whole pdf of my slides.

Comment: @Julien-ElieTaieb I see. Using different modes would probably be the beamer way to do this, e.g. beamer mode for the normal presentation and handout to create a slide with the urls.

Comment: Thx Sam carter ! I write the extract outside the frames and it works perfectly !