# Extract all includegraphics from a document

Tags: includegraphics

**My question**

I'd like to create an extract of all my graphs in a separate document.
How to extract all graphs used with `\includegraphics` in a document ?

**Context**

I used to use the `extract` package to automatically generate an external file with all the url of a Beamer presentation. However, `extract` package is not working well combined with `beamer/beamerarticle`
unless you double information you want to extract by using `\begin{extract} ... \end{extract}` outside frames (as mentionned [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/464419/strange-error-of-compilation-with-beamer-extract-and-hyperref-package)).

I could probably work on directories to find directly use the images but the names are not consistent. My working folders look like

```
chap01
     image
          image1.png
          imagewithothername2.png
.
.
.
chap18
     image
          imagxx.png
          imayyyy.png
```

** Previous not great with beamerarticle solution**

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[active,generate=images.tex,extract-cmd=section]{extract}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}  
\begin{center}      

\extractline        \includegraphics[\textwidth]{example-image-a}
    \end{center}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}  
    \begin{center}      
\extractline        \includegraphics[\textwidth]{example-image-b}
    \end{center}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}  
\lipsum
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}  
    \begin{center}      
\extractline \includegraphics[\textwidth]{example-image-c}
    \end{center}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}  
    \begin{center}      
\extractline        \includegraphics[\textwidth]{example-image-d}
    \end{center}
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```